# Много объектов типа ImageView в одной Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-imageview

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией: При создании новой Activity, на которой находится штук 10 ImageView, идет процесс переполнения памяти. Eclipse выдает следующее сообщение(красным цветом):

> dalvikvm-heap  :  Out of memory on a 9807520-byte allocation.

при этом окно закрывается.
Это происходит не постоянно. Иногда все проходит с задержкой, но окно появляется. При этом Eclipse выдает несколько сообщений (зеленым цветом):

> dalvikvm-heap : Grow heap (frag case) to 21.445MB for 3545872-byte
> allocation
>
> Choreographer : Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too
> much work on its main thread.

До этого у меня таких проблем не возникало. Что это может быть? Что я не правильно делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Написано же, что девайс страдает от вашего приложение. "Приложение делает слишком много работы в основном треде". И под конец кончается память, после чего продолжать работу вообще невозможно.

Пощадите девайс. Оптимизируйте графику, не загружайте мегабайтные кортинки, когда нужно показать лишь тумбинашку. Используйте декодеры в определенное разрешение, чтобы не выжирать память сразу. Если картинку надо скроллить, порежте ее на тайлы. В конце концов, если ничего не помогает, оставте старичка, положите его на полочку, а в документации к приложению так и напишите: "работает только на девайсах с 4 гигами оперативки".

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что в меня в окне всего 8 ImageView (картинки которых еще и повторяются). Размер картинок не более 100кб. При создании окна кроме установки прозрачности я ничего не делаю. Попробовал вообще ничего не делать, просто создать окно, не помогло. Так что тут дело в чем то другом

Comment: Я тут любил картинки от Босха смотреть, так вот на просмотр "Сада земных наслаждений" в почти нативном разрешении у меня легко 8 гигов под виндой отжиралось. Потому количеством картинок давай мерять не будем? В 100кб легко можно упихать картинку размером 100000х100000, на распаковку которой уйдет от 100000*100000*4=40.000.000.000 (40 гигабайт), чего естественно на девайсе нет и это один из путей сплоитинга приложений. Так что килобайтами тоже лучше не мерять. Лучше всего мерять размером битмапа, который получается в итоге после декодирования. И уж тем более исключать дубли картинок

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, Вы правы. Я не досмотрел, наш художник для фона слишком большое разрешение сделал. Вот фон всю память и сжирал

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь описана "предобработка" изображения перед загрузкой.. Там описано, почему могут возникнуть проблемы в работе с изображениями.
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/376-urok-161-risovanie-bitmap-memory-kesh-picasso.html

А вообще то, я бы особо не заморачивался и использовал из одну из библиотек Picasso и Glide. В сети о них информации хватает.

Comment: Это не совсем то. Все что там описано уже давно пройдено и осознано. И тут сторонние библиотеки не помогут. У меня просто создается окно на котором располагаются  8 ImageView с не большими картинками (не более 100кб каждая)